# Problems with Excel export to Word using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, export

I'm having problems exporting data from Excel to Word.
In the Excel sheet, there is a command button which first sorts the data according to date (this works). Then, the content of these columns (which are declared as variables after the sorting is done) should be exported to a Word document. 
Opening a word file works, and the first column from excel gets exported, but the remaining columns do net get their header.

This is the code

```
    Sub CreateDoc()
'Alle gegevens sorteren op datum
Range("E:Z").Select
     Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("E6"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
          Orientation:=xlLeftToRight

'Alle leerplandoelstellingen definiëren
    Dim Rij12 As String
    Rij12 = "TIJD - 1: de kijk op het levensverloop van een mens vanuit enkele levensbeschouwingen uit de eigen omgeving omschrijven en illustreren;"
    Dim Rij13 As String
    Rij13 = "TIJD - 2: de articulatie van de tijd door christenen en anderen illustreren en duiden;"
    Dim Rij14 As String
    Rij14 = "TIJD - 3: het belang bespreken van de voorgegeven tijdsstructuur (dag, nacht, week, maand, jaar, de seizoenen, …);"
    Dim Rij15 As String
    Rij15 = "TIJD - 4: enkele 'eigentijdse' feesten en/of rituelen bevragen op hun levensbeschouwelijk karakter;"
    Dim Rij16 As String
    Rij16 = "TIJD - 5: het 'in handen nemen' en het 'uit handen geven' van de eigen tijdsbeleving verwoorden;"
    Dim Rij17 As String
    Rij17 = "TIJD - 6: de eigen leeftijd in het bijzonder op het vlak van 'geloven' typeren."
    Dim Rij20 As String
    Rij20 = "VERHALEN - 1: het eigen leven omschrijven als een uniek levensverhaal;"
    Dim Rij21 As String
    Rij21 = "VERHALEN - 2: het appellerende in enkele - ook bijbelse - verhalen aangeven;"
    Dim Rij22 As String
    Rij22 = "VERHALEN - 3: de grote levensbeschouwingen profileren aan de hand van verhalen;"
    Dim Rij23 As String
    Rij23 = "VERHALEN - 4: de impact van het christelijk verhaal/levensbeschouwingen in het eigen verhaal aangeven;"
    Dim Rij24 As String
    Rij24 = "VERHALEN - 5: in vele concrete verhalen, christelijke e.a., de rode draad, dynamiek of sleutel aanduiden;"
    Dim Rij25 As String
    Rij25 = "VERHALEN - 6:het verhaal 'Jezus' opbouwen en vertellen."
    Dim Rij28 As String
    Rij28 = "GROEPEN/GEMEENSCHAPPEN - 1: verwoorden en beluisteren wat het betekent bij een groep te behoren;"
    Dim Rij29 As String
    Rij29 = "GROEPEN/GEMEENSCHAPPEN - 2: verduidelijken welke betekenis een groep kan hebben voor andere groepen en de samenleving;"
    Dim Rij30 As String
    Rij30 = "GROEPEN/GEMEENSCHAPPEN - 3: het verband aangeven tussen levensbeschouwing en groepsvorming;"
    Dim Rij31 As String
    Rij31 = "GROEPEN/GEMEENSCHAPPEN - 4: het 'eigene' van een christelijke gemeenschap opsporen en verwoorden;"
    Dim Rij32 As String
    Rij32 = "GROEPEN/GEMEENSCHAPPEN - 5: bespreken wat het betekent voor een christen in de actuele samenleving tot een minderheid te behoren;"
    Dim Rij33 As String
    Rij33 = "GROEPEN/GEMEENSCHAPPEN - 6: aangeven hoe de rondtrekkende Jezus voor en met zijn leerlingen bron van leven wordt."

'Namen van de katernen declareren als variabele
    Dim Katern1 As String
    Katern1 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(1, "E").Value
    Dim Katern2 As String
    Katern2 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(2, "E").Value
    Dim Katern3 As String
    Katern3 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(3, "E").Value
    Dim Katern4 As String
    Katern4 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(4, "E").Value
    Dim Katern5 As String
    Katern5 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(5, "E").Value
    Dim Katern6 As String
    Katern6 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "E").Value
    Dim Katern7 As String
    Katern7 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(7, "E").Value
    Dim Katern8 As String
    Katern8 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(8, "E").Value
    Dim Katern9 As String
    Katern9 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(9, "E").Value
    Dim Katern10 As String
    Katern10 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(10, "E").Value
    Dim Katern11 As String
    Katern11 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(11, "E").Value
    Dim Katern12 As String
    Katern12 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(12, "E").Value
    Dim Katern13 As String
    Katern13 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(13, "E").Value
    Dim Katern14 As String
    Katern14 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(14, "E").Value
    Dim Katern15 As String
    Katern15 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(15, "E").Value
    Dim Katern16 As String
    Katern16 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(16, "E").Value
    Dim Katern17 As String
    Katern17 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(17, "E").Value
    Dim Katern18 As String
    Katern18 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(18, "E").Value
    Dim Katern19 As String
    Katern19 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(19, "E").Value
    Dim Katern20 As String
    Katern20 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(20, "E").Value
    Dim Katern21 As String
    Katern21 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(21, "E").Value
    Dim Katern22 As String
    Katern22 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(22, "E").Value

'Inhoud van de datumcellen declareren als variabele
'Met deze methode wordt er eerst gekeken naar de inhoud van de datumcel:
'als daar nog het woord "datum" staat, dan wordt de inhoud niet opgeslagen als variabele.
OpnameDatum1:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "E").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum2
    Else: Dim Datum1 As Date
    Datum1 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "E").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum2:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "F").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum3
    Else: Dim Datum2 As Date
    Datum2 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "F").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum3:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "G").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum4
    Else: Dim Datum3 As Date
    Datum3 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "G").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum4:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "H").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum5
    Else: Dim Datum4 As Date
    Datum4 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "H").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum5:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "I").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum6
    Else: Dim Datum5 As Date
    Datum5 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "I").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum6:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "J").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum7
    Else: Dim Datum6 As Date
    Datum6 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "J").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum7:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "K").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum8
    Else: Dim Datum7 As Date
    Datum7 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "K").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum8:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "L").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum9
    Else: Dim Datum8 As Date
    Datum8 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "L").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum9:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "M").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum10
    Else: Dim Datum9 As Date
    Datum9 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "M").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum10:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "N").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum11
    Else: Dim Datum10 As Date
    Datum10 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "N").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum11:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "O").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum12
    Else: Dim Datum11 As Date
    Datum11 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "O").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum12:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "P").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum13
    Else: Dim Datum12 As Date
    Datum12 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "P").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum13:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "Q").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum14
    Else: Dim Datum13 As Date
    Datum13 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "Q").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum14:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "R").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum15
    Else: Dim Datum14 As Date
    Datum14 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "R").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum15:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "S").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum16
    Else: Dim Datum15 As Date
    Datum15 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "S").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum16:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "T").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum17
    Else: Dim Datum16 As Date
    Datum16 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "T").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum17:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "U").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum18
    Else: Dim Datum17 As Date
    Datum17 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "U").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum18:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "V").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum19
    Else: Dim Datum18 As Date
    Datum18 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "V").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum19:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "W").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum20
    Else: Dim Datum19 As Date
    Datum19 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "W").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum20:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "X").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum21
    Else: Dim Datum20 As Date
    Datum20 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "X").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum21:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "Y").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo OpnameDatum22
    Else: Dim Datum21 As Date
    Datum21 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "Y").Value
    End If
OpnameDatum22:
    If Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "Z").Value = "Datum" Then
    GoTo Waarschuwing
    Else: Dim Datum22 As Date
    Datum22 = Worksheets("Theo").Cells(6, "Z").Value
    End If

Waarschuwing:
    Dim NietIngevuld As Integer
    NietIngevuld = Application.CountIf(Sheets("Theo").Range("E6:Z6"), "Datum")
    MsgBox ("Er is bij " & NietIngevuld & " katernen geen datum ingevuld."), vbOKOnly, "Jaarplanmodule Theo 1"






'Code van de export-engine
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim docCreate As Word.Document
    'Dim rgeDoc As Range
    Dim strSaveFile As String

    strSaveFile = "C:\Jaarverslag_Theo_1.doc"

    Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
    Set docCreate = wrdApp.Documents.Add
    'Set rgeDoc = docCreate.Range
    wrdApp.Visible = True
        With wrdApp
            With .Selection
                .Font.Name = "Verdana"
                .Font.Size = 24
                .Font.Bold = True
                .TypeText Text:="             Jaarverslag Theo 1"
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 10
                .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0
                .Font.Bold = False
                .TypeParagraph
                .TypeText Text:="Naam School:"
                .TypeParagraph
                .TypeText Text:="Naam Leerkracht:"
                .TypeParagraph
                .TypeText Text:="Naam Klas:"
                .TypeParagraph
                .TypeText Text:="Schooljaar:"
                .TypeParagraph
                .TypeText Text:="_____________________________________________________________________"
OpmaakKatern1:
                If Datum1 = Empty Then
                        GoTo Afsluiten
                End If
                .TypeParagraph  'Hier start katern1
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:=Katern1     'Hier staat de naam van de katern
                .Font.Bold = False
                .Font.Underline = False
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:="Datum:"    'Hier komt de gesorteerde datum, in te lezen als variabele
                .Font.Underline = False
                .TypeText Text:=" " & Datum1   'Hier komt de gesorteerde datum, in te lezen als variabele (aanhalingstekens verwijderen voor de variabele)
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:="Gerealiseerde leerplandoelstellingen:"
                .Font.Underline = False

                'Hier checken wat de exacte inhoud van variabele Katern1 is; op basis daarvan wordt er inhoud weergegeven.
                If Katern1 = "Een nieuwe start" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EenNieuweStart
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Alles heeft zijn tijd" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_AllesHeeftZijnTijd
                ElseIf Katern1 = "De wereld aan je voeten" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_DeWereldAanJeVoeten
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Een levend boek" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EenLevendBoek
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Drempels" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Drempels
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Kerstmis" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Kerstmis
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Confituur of choco" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ConfituurOfChoco
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Hoe groot is de hemel?" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_HoeGrootIsDeHemel
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Ongelovige Thomas" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_OngelovigeThomas
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Feesten" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Feesten
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Er is er één jarig!" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ErIsErEénJarig
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Eén van hart" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EénVanHart
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Ervoor gaan" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ErvoorGaan
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Groen gras" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_GroenGras
                ElseIf Katern1 = "RELatie" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_RELatie
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Vele plaatjes" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_VelePlaatjes
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Iedereen fan" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_IedereenFan
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Schattenjacht" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Schattenjacht
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Lichtbakens" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Lichtbakens
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Rijke Luis" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_RijkeLuis
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Hemel op aarde" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_HemelOpAarde
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Op bezoek" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_OpBezoek
                End If


OpmaakKatern2:
                If Datum2 = Empty Then
                    GoTo Afsluiten
                End If
                .TypeParagraph  'Hier start katern2
                '.TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:=Katern2     'Hier staat de naam van de katern
                .Font.Bold = False
                .Font.Underline = False
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:="Datum:"    'Hier komt de gesorteerde datum, in te lezen als variabele
                .Font.Underline = False
                .TypeText Text:=" " & Datum2   'Hier komt de gesorteerde datum, in te lezen als variabele (aanhalingstekens verwijderen voor de variabele)
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:="Gerealiseerde leerplandoelstellingen:"
                .Font.Underline = False
                'Hier checken wat de exacte inhoud van variabele Katern1 is; op basis daarvan wordt er inhoud weergegeven.
                If Katern2 = "Een nieuwe start" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EenNieuweStart
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Alles heeft zijn tijd" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_AllesHeeftZijnTijd
                ElseIf Katern2 = "De wereld aan je voeten" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_DeWereldAanJeVoeten
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Een levend boek" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EenLevendBoek
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Drempels" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Drempels
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Kerstmis" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Kerstmis
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Confituur of choco" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ConfituurOfChoco
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Hoe groot is de hemel?" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_HoeGrootIsDeHemel
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Ongelovige Thomas" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_OngelovigeThomas
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Feesten" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Feesten
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Er is er één jarig!" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ErIsErEénJarig
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Eén van hart" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EénVanHart
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Ervoor gaan" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ErvoorGaan
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Groen gras" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_GroenGras
                ElseIf Katern2 = "RELatie" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_RELatie
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Vele plaatjes" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_VelePlaatjes
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Iedereen fan" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_IedereenFan
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Schattenjacht" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Schattenjacht
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Lichtbakens" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Lichtbakens
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Rijke Luis" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_RijkeLuis
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Hemel op aarde" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_HemelOpAarde
                ElseIf Katern2 = "Op bezoek" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_OpBezoek
                End If

OpmaakKatern3:
                If Datum3 = Empty Then
                        GoTo Afsluiten
                End If
                .TypeParagraph  'Hier start katern3
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:=Katern3     'Hier staat de naam van de katern
                .Font.Bold = False
                .Font.Underline = False
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:="Datum:"    'Hier komt de gesorteerde datum, in te lezen als variabele
                .Font.Underline = False
                .TypeText Text:=" " & Datum3   'Hier komt de gesorteerde datum, in te lezen als variabele (aanhalingstekens verwijderen voor de variabele)
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:="Gerealiseerde leerplandoelstellingen:"
                .Font.Underline = False
                'Hier checken wat de exacte inhoud van variabele Katern1 is; op basis daarvan wordt er inhoud weergegeven.
                If Katern3 = "Een nieuwe start" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EenNieuweStart
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Alles heeft zijn tijd" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_AllesHeeftZijnTijd
                ElseIf Katern3 = "De wereld aan je voeten" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_DeWereldAanJeVoeten
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Een levend boek" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EenLevendBoek
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Drempels" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Drempels
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Kerstmis" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Kerstmis
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Confituur of choco" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ConfituurOfChoco
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Hoe groot is de hemel?" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_HoeGrootIsDeHemel
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Ongelovige Thomas" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_OngelovigeThomas
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Feesten" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Feesten
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Er is er één jarig!" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ErIsErEénJarig
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Eén van hart" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EénVanHart
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Ervoor gaan" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ErvoorGaan
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Groen gras" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_GroenGras
                ElseIf Katern3 = "RELatie" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_RELatie
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Vele plaatjes" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_VelePlaatjes
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Iedereen fan" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_IedereenFan
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Schattenjacht" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Schattenjacht
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Lichtbakens" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Lichtbakens
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Rijke Luis" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_RijkeLuis
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Hemel op aarde" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_HemelOpAarde
                ElseIf Katern3 = "Op bezoek" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_OpBezoek
                End If

Invulling_EenNieuweStart:
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij20_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij20
                End If
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij28_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij28
                End If
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij30_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij30
                End If


Invulling_AllesHeeftZijnTijd:
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij12_1.Value = True Then
                   .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij12
                End If
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij13_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij13
                End If
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij14_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij14
                End If
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij16_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij16
                End If
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij22_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij22
                End If



Invulling_DeWereldAanJeVoeten:
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij20_2.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij20
                End If
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij21_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij21
                End If
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij23_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij23
                End If
                If Worksheets("Theo").Rij24_1.Value = True Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .TypeText Text:=Rij24
                End If

End With

        End With

Set wrdApp = Nothing

'Data in Excel weer sorteren volgens de volgorde van de inhoudstafel
Eindsorteren:
Range("E:Z").Select
        Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("E8"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
            Orientation:=xlLeftToRight

Afsluiten:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to be storing the headings in the E column, in which case, your sort range should not start at E, but at F. After that, the macro really needs a lot of tidying, it would make your life a lot easier. You may wish consider arrays for storing data and you may wish to get rid of a lot of those labels.

Answer (score 0):

Is an empty date value being found which is resulting in `GoTo Afsluiten` (exit sub) getting called prematurely? Also, you're missing some labels. For example, you have `GoTo Invulling_OpBezoek` but there is no corresponding `Invulling_OpBezoek` label. It's hard for me to tell you exactly what's wrong without seeing the actual Excel data, but those would be my first guesses. As Remou said, you should try to avoid labels and GoTo statements. You should also try using arrays to store some of those values. Here's a quick and dirty cleanup of the code you posted. I took some of the Word formatting code out for simplicity but it should give you an idea of the direction you should go with this. I also only added code to one of the select case statements because, as I said, not all your GoTo statements had corresponding labels.

```
Sub CreateDoc()

Dim Katern(21) As String, DatumValues(21) As String
Dim TheoSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, NietIngevuld As Integer

'Alle gegevens sorteren op datum
Range("E6").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("E6"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight

Set TheoSheet = Worksheets("Theo")

'Namen van de katernen declareren als variabele
For i = LBound(Katern) To UBound(Katern)

    Katern(i) = TheoSheet.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value

Next i

For i = LBound(DatumValues) To UBound(DatumValues)

    If TheoSheet.Cells(6, i + 6).Value <> "Datum" Then

        DatumValues(i) = TheoSheet.Cells(6, i + 6).Value

    End If

Next i

NietIngevuld = Application.CountIf(TheoSheet.Range("E6:Z6"), "Datum")
MsgBox ("Er is bij " & NietIngevuld & " katernen geen datum ingevuld."), vbOKOnly, "Jaarplanmodule Theo 1"

'Code van de export-engine
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim docCreate As Word.Document
Dim strSaveFile As String
Dim body As Word.Range

strSaveFile = "C:\Jaarverslag_Theo_1.doc"

Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
Set docCreate = wrdApp.Documents.Add
wrdApp.Visible = True

Set body = docCreate.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)

body.Text = "             Jaarverslag Theo 1" & Chr(13)
body.InsertAfter "Naam School:" & Chr(13)
body.InsertAfter "Naam Leerkracht:" & Chr(13)
body.InsertAfter "Naam Klas:" & Chr(13)
body.InsertAfter "Schooljaar:" & Chr(13)
body.InsertAfter "_____________________________________________________________________" & Chr(13)

For i = LBound(DatumValues) To UBound(DatumValues)

    If DatumValues(i) = "" Then

        Exit Sub

    End If

    body.InsertAfter Chr(13) & Katern(i) & Chr(13)
    body.InsertAfter "Datum: " & DatumValues(i) & Chr(13)
    body.InsertAfter "Gerealiseerde leerplandoelstellingen:"

    Select Case Katern(i)

        Case "Een nieuwe start"

            If TheoSheet.Rij20_1.Value Then

                body.InsertAfter "your text string here"

            ElseIf TheoSheet.Rij28_1.Value Then

                body.InsertAfter "your text string here"

            ElseIf TheoSheet.Rij30_1.Value Then

                body.InsertAfter "your text string here"

            End If

        Case "Alles heeft zijn tijd"
            'do stuff
        Case "De wereld aan je voeten"
            'do stuff
        Case "Een levend boek"
            'do stuff
        Case "Drempels"
            'do stuff
        Case "Kerstmis"
            'do stuff
        Case "Confituur of choco"
            'do stuff
        Case "Hoe groot is de hemel?"
            'do stuff
        Case "Ongelovige Thomas"
            'do stuff
        Case "Feesten"
            'do stuff
        Case "Er is er één jarig!"
            'do stuff
        Case "Eén van hart"
            'do stuff
        Case "Ervoor gaan"
            'do stuff
        Case "Groen gras"
            'do stuff
        Case "RELatie"
            'do stuff
        Case "Vele plaatjes"
            'do stuff
        Case "Iedereen fan"
            'do stuff
        Case "Schattenjacht"
            'do stuff
        Case "Lichtbakens"
            'do stuff
        Case "Rijke Luis"
            'do stuff
        Case "Hemel op aarde"
            'do stuff
        Case "Op bezoek"
            'do stuff

    End Select

Next i

Set wrdApp = Nothing

'Data in Excel weer sorteren volgens de volgorde van de inhoudstafel
Range("E:Z").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("E8"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

find all instances of Header:=xlGuess and change them to Header:=xlYes